# How to make a space in between words and letters in html?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a problem to auto separate when input field detect between words and letters in html. For example expected result, when I type "ABB9102", the input field auto change to "ABB 9102".

Below is my coding, this coding just can restrict in-front 3 characters, cannot detect between words and letters, if I type "ABCD9102", it cannot auto change to "ABCD 9102":

```js
function space(str, after) {
  if (!str) {
    return false;
  }
  after = after || 3;
  var v = str.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
    reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g");
  return v.replace(reg, function(a) {
    return a + ' ';
  });
}

var el = document.getElementById('pin');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = space(this.value, 3);
});
```

```html
  <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength=20 type="text" placeholder="type the pin" id="pin" name="pin" />
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: In the field above you cannot type letters

Comment: Got bugs, need fix it.

Comment: So, it should only replace, if there are at least 3 characters in front? AB123 should not get a space but, ABC123 should be changed to ABC 123?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want?

```
<input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength=20 type="text" placeholder="type the pin" id="pin" name="pin" />
```

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('pin');

function make_space () {
    var content = el.value;
    var patt = content.match(/[^\d|^\s]\d/g);
    var x;

    if (patt != null)
        for (x of patt) {
            el.value = content.replace(x, x[0] + " " + x[1])
            content = el.value;
        }

    var content = el.value;
    var patt = content.match(/\d[^\d|^\s]/g);
    var x;

    if (patt != null)
        for (x of patt) {
            el.value = content.replace(x, x[0] + " " + x[1])
            content = el.value;
        }
}

el.addEventListener('keyup', make_space);
el.addEventListener('change', make_space);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function space(str) {
      if (str) {
        const getIntialThree = str.slice(0,3)
        const restThreeLetter = str.slice(3)
        const result = `${getIntialThree} ${restThreeLetter}`;
        console.log(result)
      }{
      return false
   }
}
```

```
// testing

const number = 'ABB9102'
space(number)

//output
> "ABB 9102"
```